# SQL Server Insert New Record if Not Exists, If Exists Update In C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I Need to know SQl Query, how to insert new record into sql server if the record is not exists or  if the record exists update the record.

The below one what i tried

```
string sql=   "if record not exists (select * from  OpCircular Where circular_No='" + tbcicularno.Text.Trim() + "') INSERT INTO OpCircular(circular_No, fromDate, toDate, empId) VALUES ('" + tbcicularno.Text.Trim() + "','" +from+ "','" + to + "','Testing') If not Exists Update Set fromDate='" +from+ "'"
```

Comment: What you want is SCD1 implementation. Read this [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/managing-slowly-changing-dimension-with-merge-statement-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: Do know that the code you show here is vulnerable for Sql Injection attacks. Use SqlCommandParameters.

Comment: @rene Yes i Know it, but this program only using inside of our organization.

Comment: That is not an excuse, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this,
example:

```
if exists(select 1 from table where id = 4) 
begin
 (do what u want)
end
else
begin
 (do what u want)
end
```

Comment: Thats What i want, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM Article WHERE CategoryId = 3)
    BEGIN
       -- Update Script 
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN 
       -- Insert Script
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check all the record in the table while insert the new record and the do your required operation.

You can do following:

declare the counter variable and initialize it with 0

`declare @icnt int  = 0`

now check the record from table and store the count in the variable:

`set @icnt = select count(*) from 'YourTableName' where (here you need to check all the fields with "and" condition)`

now if the column exists then your `@icnt` value will become 1 otherwise it will remain 0. So, set if..else condition like this.

`if(@icnt > 0)
begin
(Put your update query here)
end
else
(Put your insert query here)
end`

for more, you can also do like [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use a stored procedure, as it has a lot of benefits and you can be protected against SQL Injection attacks. Here is a sample SP that inserts a record in a table if the given ID does not exist and returns the IDENTITY or it just updates it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_product_insert_update]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@id int=NULL,
@description nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE Product
SET Description=@description
WHERE Id=@id


IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0)
    INSERT INTO Product (Description)
    OUTPUT Inserted.ID
    VALUES (@description)

END
```

On the SQL Management Studio 
this call will insert a record and will return the ID=1

```
usp_product_insert_update null,'Demo'
```

This call will update the record where ID=1

```
usp_product_insert_update 1,'Demo2'
```

Comment: Thank you i will Work on it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for sql-server since 2008:

```
MERGE INTO OpCircular WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target  
USING
(SELECT :circular_No as circular_No) as source
ON
(target.circular_No = source.circular_No)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET fromDate = :fromDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (circular_No, fromDate, toDate, empId)
                      VALUES (:circular_No, :fromDate, :toDate, 'Testing');
```

*Note: All [**:identifier**] are just placeholders for your external data*